# What would be the LINQ solution for this query in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class `RuleDetail`:

```
public class RuleDetail
{
   public int RuleDetailId;
   public int StartYear;
}
```

I have a List of objects of type `RuleDetail`:

> RuleDetailId=1, StartYear=0 
>   RuleDetailId=2, StartYear=2 
>   RuleDetailId=3, StartYear=4  
>   RuleDetailId=4, StartYear=10 
>   RuleDetailId=5, StartYear=13 
>  
>   RuleDetailId=6, StartYear=18

I will be given a number say **x** (**x** always >= 0); for that I need to find the `RuleDetail` object in the above List which matches these conditions:

1. Get the `RuleDetail` object where **x** equals to StartYear OR
2. Get the `RuleDetail` object of the max(StartYear) when StartYear < **x**

Assuming I have these variables

```
RuleDetail[] ruleDetails = null;
int x = -1;
// ruleDetails populated
// x populated
```

This is the code I have come up with:

```
bool found = false;
RuleDetail ruleDetail = null;
RuleDetail oldRuleDetail = null;

for (int i=0; i<ruleDetails.Length; i++)
{
   if (ruleDetails[i].StartYear == x)
   {
      found = true;
      ruleDetail = ruleDetails[i];
      break;
   }
   else if (ruleDetails[i].StartYear > x)
   {
      found = true;
      ruleDetail = oldRuleDetail;
      break;
   }

   oldRuleDetail = ruleDetails[i];
}
if (!found)
{
    ruleDetail = oldRuleDetail;
}
return ruleDetail;
```

The code is working ok. But how can I do this in LINQ?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure the solution you provided is correct? what if `ruleDetails[1].StartYear == x + 1`  and  `ruleDetails[2].StartYear == x`?

Comment: The `RuleDetail` objects in `ruleDetails[]` are ordered by StartYear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var output = ruleDetails.OrderBy(rule => rule.StartYear).Where(rule => rule.StartYear <= x).Last()
```

If the list is already in StartYear order then ....

```
var output = ruleDetails.Where(rule => rule.StartYear <= x).Last()
```

Comment: your list of RuleDetails - if you're sure they are in order - you can lose the OrderBy ...

Comment: ok. Can you change `list` to `ruleDetails`? It will make it easier to understand

Comment: You don't need the AsEnumerable - List and Array implement IEnumerable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
ruleDetails.FirstOrDefault(rd => rd.StartYear == x)
    ?? ruleDetails.Where(rd => rd.StartYear < x).OrderByDescending(rd => rd.StartYear).First();
```

which is a clear separation of your two requirements, but it is actually more concise to use

```
ruleDetails.Where(rd => rd.StartYear <= x).OrderByDescending(rd => rd.StartYear).First()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var res1 = (from a in ruleDetails where a.StartYear == x select a).First();
var res2 = (from a in ruleDetails orderby a.StartYear where a.StartYear < x select a).Last();
```

Comment: 2 solutions to the question?

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a real simple LINQ snippet to accomplish what you're trying to do here. I'm writing this with the assumption that your list is ordered as that's what your current code suggests.

We'll first filter the list down to entries that are either the target year or less than it, then take the highest remaining element.

```
var filteredList = ruledetails.Where(r => r.StartYear <= targetYear);
return filteredList.Last;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda gross, but maybe something like:

```
       var result = ruleDetails
            .OrderBy(r => r.StartYear)
            .FirstOrDefault(r => r.StartYear == x || r.StartYear == ruleDetails.Select(y => y.StartYear).Max());
```

Answer (score 1):

(A) if the list is is initially sorted by `StartYear`, then

```
var result = ruleDetails.LastOrDefault(r => r.StartYear <= startYear);
```

(B)  if the list is not sorted, then

```
var result = ruleDetails.Where(r => r.StartYear <= startYear)
    .Aggregate((RuleDetail)null, (a, b) => a == null || a.StartYear < b.StartYear ? b : a);
```